# How to detect architecture of an LE (linear executable) file?

Tags: windows, executable-format

What instruction set architecture does an [LE (linear executable) file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.exe#OS/2) have? The linked article says: *mixed 16/32 bit*.

1. Does it mean that the same LE file can contain 16-bit and 32-bit code?
2. How do I detect whether it contains 16-bit (8086) code?
3. How do I detect whether it contains 32-bit (i386) code?

Please note that I'm aware of the *CPU type* field (see [here](http://faydoc.tripod.com/formats/exe-LE.htm)) which can distinguish between 80286 and i386 (80386). However, I interpret this as a CPU type requirement, so this doesn't specify the architecture, e.g. the hex `40` is valid in both: it means `inc ax` in 16-bit code and it means `inc eax` in 32-bit code, and both can be executed by a 80386 CPU. I'm interested in what hex `40` means in the code of an LE file.

Comment: To the downvoter: Can you suggest a way I can improve this question? I was working on it very carefully to make it specific and easy to answer (for those who know the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find https://www.program-transformation.org/Transform/PcExeFormat , based on which the answer is the following.

If object flag bit 13 in the object table entry is set, then it's 32-bit, otherwise it's 16-bit.

In the executable entry table, LE flag bit 1 of LX bundle type byte distinguishes between 16-bit and 32-bit.

Since there can be multiple entries in these tables, a single LE or LX file may contain both 16-bit and 32-bit code.